# How to remove addClsOnOver listener ExtJS

Tags: javascript, css, button, extjs, hover

When a button is clicked, I use `addClsOnOver` to change the over cls of the button and it works fine. The second time the button is clicked, `addClsOnOver` is called again but with a different class and this is expected to happen multiple times but unfortunately, the event listeners created by `addClsOnOver` are not over-written after the first click.
I know now that I need to use `removeListener()` and then `addClsOnOver` if I want to change it again after the first time but dont know what parameters to put in it to remove the `addClsOnOver` listener.
I'm sure its fairly simple but I'm out of guesses atm and cant find anything in the docs that might suggest what the auto-generated listener might be called.

Help please? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not set fn parameter in [`removeListener()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element-method-removeListener) method, all listeners for specified event will be removed.

So if you do not use your own listeners for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` on button element you can use for removing listeners seted by `addClsOnOver()` method this code:

```
// use el.dom as scope because it is used el.hover method when listeners were created
el.removeListener('mouseenter', null, el.dom);
el.removeListener('mouseleave', null, el.dom);
```

Fiddle with example: **https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/30d**

Comment: dude, thank you sooo much! Saved me a century of work <3