# ExtJs on click fires number of times the window is opened

Tags: extjs

In the before render event of the window. i have this code

```
Ext.define('Ext.view.ReaderWindow', {
  extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
  alias: 'widget.reader',
  id1: 0,
  file_path: '',
  id: 'reader',
  itemId: 'reader',
  maxHeight: 800,
  maxWidth: 900,
  minHeight: 300,
  minWidth: 500,
  layout: {
    type: 'anchor'
  },
  title: 'File Reader',
  modal: true,

  initComponent: function() {
  var me = this;

  Ext.applyIf(me, {
    items: [{
      xtype: 'form',
      anchor: '100% 100%',
      itemId: 'reader_form',
      maxHeight: 800,
      maxWidth: 900,
      minHeight: 300,
      minWidth: 500,
      autoScroll: true,
      bodyPadding: 10,
      items: [{
        xtype: 'displayfield',
        anchor: '100%',
        itemId: 'file_contents',
        maxWidth: 900,
        minWidth: 50,
        hideLabel: true,
        name: 'file_contents'
      }]
    }],
    listeners: {
      beforerender: {
        fn: me.reader_windowBeforeRender,
        scope: me
      }
    }
  });

  me.callParent(arguments);
  },

  reader_windowBeforeRender: function(component, eOpts) {

    Ext.model.FileReaderModel.load(this.id1, {
      params: {
        'file':        this.file_path
      },
      success: function(file_reader) {
        var form_panel = current.query('#reader_form');
        var contents_field = form_panel[0].getComponent('file_contents');
        var contents = file_reader.get('file_contents');
        var pattern = /(\/.*?\.\S*)/gi;
        contents = contents.replace(pattern, "<a href='#' class='sample'>$1</a>");
        contents_field.setValue('<pre>' + contents + '</pre>');

        Ext.select('.sample').on('click', function() {
          var path = this.innerHTML;
          var Id1 = this.id1;
          var reader = Ext.create('Ext.view.ReaderWindow', {
            id1: Id1,
            file_path:  path
          });

         reader.show();

        });
      },
      failure: function(file_reader, response) {
      }
    });

  },
});
```

for "a tag" i have assigned "sample" class. When a link is clicked, it opens a new window (but the same window is used to show the content).

The problem is if i click the a tag first time, then on click is called once. Then after i close the window and click a tag again..this time it fires twice. So depending on number of times i open and close..the click event is called so many times.

It looks like every time i open the window same event is registered multiple times. But i want to register the event only once.Any time i click a link, only once it should call the click event.

Comment: please add the rest of the relevant code, no way to tell what's happening without it

Comment: `Ext.select` goes through the entire HTML document.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove addClsOnOver listener ExtJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21370277/how-to-remove-addclsonover-listener-extjs)